Search among files of a C++ project (located on QNX) containing a given Structure/Class/Object/Void
There is a large project in QNX written in C++, which contains many .h, .cpp, .o files, etc.
One of the .cpp files constantly references several functions. One of them is called "MapABC", and the second is "GrooveySignRestore".
I want to understand how this functions work, but they are located somewhere among dozens of other files.
How can I find a file containing a description of the desired function in QNX, among other files?
